# MISSING_CREDENTIAL No credential is found for oss.sonatype.org

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-sonatype

I try to publish my project to Maven Central using the sbt-sonatype Plugin.

Following the instructions here: https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype#buildsbt

I have this configuration:

```
  lazy val publicationSettings: Project => Project = _.settings(
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    publishTo := sonatypePublishToBundle.value,
    sonatypeCredentialHost := "s01.oss.sonatype.org",
    sonatypeRepository := "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local",
    ...
```

The credentials `~/.sbt/1.0/sonatype.sbt`:

```
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager",
        "s01.oss.sonatype.org",
        "myUser",
        "myPassword")
```

`plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "2.1.2")
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "3.9.7")
```

But somehow it still looks for the credentials for `oss.sonatype.org`:

```
sbt> sonatypeBundleRelease
[MISSING_CREDENTIAL] No credential is found for oss.sonatype.org. Prepare ~/.sbt/(sbt_version)/sonatype.sbt file.
    at xerial.sbt.sonatype.SonatypeClient.$anonfun$directCredentials$1(SonatypeClient.scala:45)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
```

If I change the host to `oss.sonatype.org` in the credentials I get the following:

```
2021-04-18 17:53:04.183+0200  info [SonatypeService] sonatypeRepository  : https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local  - (SonatypeService.scala:23)
2021-04-18 17:53:04.185+0200  info [SonatypeService] sonatypeProfileName : pme123  - (SonatypeService.scala:24)
2021-04-18 17:53:04.186+0200  info [SonatypeClient] Reading staging repository profiles...  - (SonatypeClient.scala:108)
[info] Preparing a new staging repository for [sbt-sonatype] camunda-dmn-tester-root 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT
2021-04-18 17:53:04.544+0200  info [SonatypeClient] Reading staging profiles...  - (SonatypeClient.scala:120)
2021-04-18 17:53:04.685+0200 error [Sonatype] 
wvlet.airframe.http.HttpClientException: [403: Forbidden] Request failed: <html>
  <head>
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? How? @pme

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the settings are only taken if running the command in the `project`.

```
sbt> project server
sbt> sonatypeBundleRelease
```

This works or at least fixes this problem.